# Resource "kubernetes_service_account" cannot be made depend_on resource "aws_eks_cluster"

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks, eksctl, terraform-provider-kubernetes

I'm trying to create EKS Cluster using terraform and also wanted to create few services after the creation of the cluster. But when i tried to add depends_on it doesn't work.

```
resource "aws_eks_cluster" "eks" {
  name = "${var.clustername}"
  version = "${var.kubeversion}"
  role_arn = aws_iam_role.eks-iam-role.arn
  enabled_cluster_log_types = ["api", "authenticator", "audit", "scheduler", "controllerManager"]
  vpc_config {
    endpoint_private_access = true
    endpoint_public_access  = false
    subnet_ids = [var.subnet_id_1, var.subnet_id_2]
  }
  kubernetes_network_config {
    ip_family         = "ipv4"
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_role.eks-iam-role,
  ]
}
```

I also wanted to create a namespace after the cluster has been created so i added below code which is failing with an error even after adding depends_on

```
#Creating namespace as test
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "test" {
  metadata {
    annotations = {
      name = "test-annotation"
    }

    labels = {
      mylabel = "test-label"
    }

    name = "test"
  }
  depends_on = [
    aws_eks_cluster.eks,
  ]
}
```

Error:

```
Error: Get "http://localhost/api/v1/namespaces/test": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused
```

I've added the authentication info in kubernetes provider but however the namespace creation should be skipped before the cluster has been created.

Any thoughts??

```
I tried adding the depends_on in resource "kubernetes_namespace" which should wait until the cluster has been created but it doesn't. I'm expecting the resources to be created only after the cluster has been created.
```

Comment: How are you expecting your kubernetes namespace resource to be able to talk to your aws eks cluster???

Comment: Have you even defined kubernetes in the `required_providers` and cofigured the provider to use EKS credentials?

Comment: Yes and then i was able to connect it.